# jQuery AJAX call for simple site

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

I have made a simple site that you enter an access code and it reveals a seceret message. It works. wooo.

However, i would like to add a bit too it so when the seceret has been revealed, an email is sent to the user in the background.

I know i use ajax for the call to the PHP script that would send the email, but im a little unsure of the code to use.

I know the users email address already, as the site is for that person.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show how your code looks so far?

Comment: Have you read about [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) yet?  Start there if not.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "your_php_url",
  data: "email="+email,
  success:function(response) {
    alert("Mail sent");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the php script that you call via ajax, you could just do something along these lines:

```
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

If you had this html:

```
<a href="#" id="callphp">trigger ajax request</a>
```

You could hook up the following with jQuery:

```
$('#callphp').bind('click', function(){
     $.ajax({
        url: "yourscript.php",
        success: function(){
           alert("done");
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: i know the PHP part, but the ajax/jquery part?

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to blogger from: http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/ --and quoting directly (posted link for credits and extra information)

Define constants somewhere:

```
define('GUSER', 'you@gmail.com'); // GMail username
define('GPWD', 'password'); // GMail password
```

Store this function:

```
function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = GUSER;  
    $mail->Password = GPWD;           
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then the PHP file to be called via ajax would contain:

```
<?php
smtpmailer('to@mail.com', '', 'from@mail.com', 'yourName', 'test mail message', 'Hello World!');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery.ajax function. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "url",
  type: "POST",
  data: "email="+email,
  success:function(response) {
       console.log("success");
  }
});
```